# How to Schedule onMessage() method of JMS Listener

Tags: jms, spring-jms, spring-scheduled

I want that my listener will run in a interval of **'x' minutes**, I have gone through **@Scheduled** annotation of Spring, but I am not sure how to use it with jms listener, I would appreciate if anyone inputs on the same -

```
Here is my code snippet of Consumer

@Override @Scheduled(cron="0 */x * * * *")
  public void onMessage(Message message) {
   try {
    LOG.info("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
    MailMessageObject response = (MailMessageObject)messageConverter.fromMessage(message);
    LOG.info("Application : failed message as a response: {}", response);
    LOG.info("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
// Here we are getting failed message, again create mail and will           // send thru java mail
            SendMessageHelper help = new SendMessageHelper();
            help.abstractEmailSender(response);

    }
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42925870/control-message-listener-container-to-stop-for-certain-period-and-start-again-to/42929047#42929047

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work that way - the listener is message-driven and will run whenever a message is received.

If you want to fetch messages based on a schedule, use a `JmsTemplate.receive(...)` method instead (with a timeout to handle when there are no messages).