# stop jmsListener when message in MQ is empty

Tags: java, spring, jms, spring-jms, mq

I use the Listener to read the messages from MQ as mentioned in the link [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0609_alcott/0609_alcott.html)

**ExampleMessageListener :**
This implements the onMessage method of Interface javax.jms.MessageListener

Listener :

```
   <bean id="messageListener" class="sample.ExampleMessageListener" />

   <bean id="msgListenerContainer"
      class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
      <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory" />
      <property name="destination" ref="jmsQueue" />
      <property name="messageListener" ref="messageListener" />
   </bean>

   <jee:jndi-lookup id="jmsConnectionFactory" jndi-name="jms/CF1" />

   <jee:jndi-lookup id="jmsQueue" jndi-name="jms/jmsQueue" />
```

I want to stop the listener when all the messages in MQ are read? (In other words, stop the listener when no meessages in MQ)

Any best way to identify the unavailability of messages in MQ?

Answer (score 0):

using jms Browser ?

```
session.createBrowser(session.createQueue("Q"))
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Session.html#createBrowser-javax.jms.Queue-

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/QueueBrowser.html#getEnumeration--

to start and stop the DMLC see here [control-message-listener-container-to-stop-for-certain-period-and-start-again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42925870/control-message-listener-container-to-stop-for-certain-period-and-start-again-to/42929047#42929047)